# I am getting Response data error as"The resource owner or authorization server denied the request"

Tags: jmeter

My Application is having Oath Authentication so recorded particular test scripts getting failed.I have analysed and found the token details in the login response data

```
{"access_token":"EsDRTzicGpSjaj8xcdEFBQ8aHbTt6btVW35Y4scQ","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":28800,"refresh_token":"XhpFEDvCrGhwz9J4lPkRd0MMfQqUiW7j0zmbcPGr"}
```

**Scenario1:**
So Added Authorization:Bearer${BEARER} in the HTTP Header manager below the sampler  and executed the TC its getting failed with the below message

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"The resource owner or authorization server denied the request."}
```

**Scenario 2:** 
Getting the below  message if i didn't add the Authorization:Bearer${BEARER} in the HTTP Header manager

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."}
```

Need to know which one is right and how to overcome form this issue

Comment: are you sure that ${Bearer} has the right value? also in this kind of auth, usually there is a space between "bearer" and "token" in the authorization header

Comment: There is a  space between "bearer" and "token"

Comment: yes, i mean is it there in your script you could have missed it because its not there in your question, and did you check ${bearer} contains the right value?

Comment: ${bearer} contains the right value? I have not declared any thing for bearer  just i have mentioned in HTTP header thats all

Comment: ${bearer} is a var that contain the token extracted from the login response right? so check if it is extracting the token by adding a view result tree listener and a debug sampler

Comment: Can you share any link or procedure to configure that

Comment: Bearer has been declared as Name:Prefix and Value :Bearer in the user Defined variable with Regular expression extractor and debug sampler below the login sampler and the immediate sampler has been passed and the remaining sampler has been failed how to declare common so that all the sampler can pass

Comment: @Irshad, you can to declare `User Defined Variable` in your `Test Plan`, so that the scope is global. Click on `Test Plan` and add the variables and values.

Comment: Thanks got it and worked pleas answer so that can rate u

Comment: Hi @Irshad, Are you referring my comment or ararar's one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Please follow as per the image]

1. Declare a variable below the test plan with `Name:Prefix` and `value:Bearer`
2. Add regular expression Extractor with reference name & Expression below the sampler
3. Add a debug sampler to identify the Token and run the test plan

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) specification you must have a space bar between `Bearer` and the token value

   ```
   Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
                        ^ nothing should be here
   ```
2. OAuth token is not something you can record and replay, the value needs to be obtained using specific procedure which might be different depending on [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) version and implementation. Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) guide for more information on how you can obtain the OAuth token in JMeter test.